# Tangent to two parametric curves

Tags: parametric, tangent-line

If I have two parametric curves one defined as x(t) and y(t) and another x(s)+c and y(s).

My assumption is that if I set t = s = value. I can find the two slopes at these values. i.e. dy/dx = x'(t)y'(t) but what I am after is a tangent between the two curves and this will depend on the x-axis shift, in this case c, which does not factor in the derivatives.

So my question is can the common tangent be determined? If so does it depend on setting a ratio between s and t that somehow depends on c?

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for the tangent to be "between" the two curves?

Comment: You surely mean "common tangent(s)"

Comment: Edited to say common tangent.

Comment: If you know how to find intersection points between parametric curves, then for plane curves you can intersect the dual curves...

Comment: Without knowing more about the curves I don't think so. For instance, x(t) = t, y(t) = t would not have a line tangent to both curves anywhere for nonzero c

Comment: I don't see the need to use this constant $c$. Do we agree you have two pairs of **different** curves $(x=x_1(t),y=y_1(t))$ and $(x=x_2(t),y=y_2(t))$ ? Could you say in particular whether $x_2$ is or isn't defined as $x_1+c$ ? The best would be to provide an example for both parametric equations.

Comment: Yes the two curves are different i.e. not the same functions and displaced on the x axis. If that is solvable then need to consider a displacement on both axis.

Comment: Okay maybe I can explain things better. If I have two circles of different radius, separated by a distance c, then one can find a common tangent by using a helper circle. Now if you express the circles as parametric curves x(u) = cos(u) y(u) = sin(u) or x(t)=1-t^2/ 1+t^2 and y(t)=2t/1+t^2. For different radius I assume one multiplies the parametric curves by the different radius. Can one find the common tangent using the parametric curves and the separation. If yes can one do the same be done for different curves.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Take the circle $(r_1\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},r_1\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$ centered at the origin and the circle $(h+r_2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},k+r_2\frac{2t}{1+t^2}),$ centered at $(h,k)$ then by looking at the [dual curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve)s ($(\frac{-y'}{xy'-x'y},\frac{x'}{xy'-x'y})$) $(-\frac1{r_1}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},-\frac1{r_1}\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$ and $(\frac{(t^2-1)}{((r_2-h)t^2+2kt+r_2+h)}
,-\frac{(2t)}{((r_2-h)t^2+2kt+r_2+h)})$ we get intersection points

$(-(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}-hr_2+hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1),(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}+kr_2-kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1)),((k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}+hr_2-hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1),-(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}-kr_2+kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1),
(-(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}+hr_2+hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1),
(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}-kr_2-kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1)),
((k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}-hr_2-hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1),
-(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}+kr_2+kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1))$

corresponding to common tangents $-(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}-hr_2+hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) x+(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}+kr_2-kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) y+1=0,(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}+hr_2-hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) x-(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2-r_1)^2}-kr_2+kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) y +1=0, 
-(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}+hr_2+hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) x+
(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}-kr_2-kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) y+1=0,
(k\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}-hr_2-hr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) x
-(h\sqrt{h^2+k^2-(r_2+r_1)^2}+kr_2+kr_1)/((k^2+h^2)r_1) y+1=0.$

[image: common tangents to parametric curves]